# Is there RFC 5261 (XML patch) implementation in ruby?

Tags: ruby, xml

I am looking to way to use [An Extensible Markup Language (XML) Patch perations Framework Utilizing XML Path Language (XPath) Selectors](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5261) in ruby.

I have source xml files and patch xml files (extracted from X Rebirth game) and would like to get resulting xml.

There is [libxmlpath](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlpatch/) library, but i prefer native solution.

Comment: If this question offtopic on SO, where it can be asked?

Comment: perhaps this will help https://github.com/mbklein/equivalent-xml

Comment: thanks @knowbody, but equivalent-xml can't help me in any way, it only allow to compare some xml nodes. I need to apply xml patch to xml file.

Comment: the only other thing I've seen was `libxmlpath` you mentioned

Comment: found Java implementation https://github.com/dnault/xml-patch